# Interface for transfering files between alfresco and fedena

Tags: alfresco, fedena

I want to make an interface between Alfresco and Fedena which takes a corresponding document from the Fedena and puts it into Alfresco (and can also go from Alfresco to Fedena).

How would I do this?

Comment: if you are looking for a document manager, fedena already have a document managent plugin and Fedena also has plugin for google doc integration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of fedena.But in case of alfresco e can do this using 2 days.Both of them are as below.

**1.Using CMIS API which is  provided by alfresco**

Below are some use full links for that.

> http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS
>    http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/topics/cmis-welcome.html

**2.Rest Api using webscript**
For this you need to create webscript on your own.Basic details regarding webscript can be found on below link

> https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts
>   http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/ws-hello-world-create.html